# How can I alter node reference in drupal

Tags: php, drupal

How can I alter node reference in drupal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trough [hook_nodeapi](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) like you modify or alter any other `$node->` piece.

But make sure the module that does the altering is called *after* both *cck/content* and *nodereference* modules. You do this by changing the `weight` in the `system` database-table*).

*) Yes, you do that by poking around in the database. And no, there is nothing wrong with that :)